# Creating an ArrayList for a student roster

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an assignment that will be used to search and sort a student roster. The user will be able to input a students name, remove a student, check enrollment of a student, print the roster, get the number of students, or quit. What I need help with is setting up the array to store the users input. I'm extremely new to arrays and do not really know where to start with the array list. Once I figure out how to set up the array list, I can then add in the different options for each case and make this program functional. Here is the code, and now I need help with adding an array list to store the choice.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExerciseSix {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int choice;
        String name;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What would you like to do?");
        System.out.println("1 - Add a student");
        System.out.println("2 - Remove a student");
        System.out.println("3 - Check enrollment of a student");
        System.out.println("4 - Print the roster");
        System.out.println("5 - Get the number of enrolled students");
        System.out.println("6 - Quit");
        choice = input.nextInt();

        switch (choice) {

        case 1:
            System.out.println("Enter name of student to add.");
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("Enter name of student to remove.");
            break;

        case 3:
            break;

        case 4:
            break;

        case 5:
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("You have chosen to quit");
            break;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: array.add(...) ? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)

Comment: Exactly what is your question?

Comment: Your question is confusing, Do you want to show user name and their selection. like, Frank - 2, Albert - 1, …?

Comment: I want to know how to add an array list that can store the users name

Answer (score 1):

*I want to know how to add an array list that can store the users name*

```
List<String> studentList = new ArrayList<String>();
studentList.add("Jon");
studentList.add("Doe");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<String> students = new ArrayList<String>();
```

But you will probably find you need more than just a name for each student, in which case you will want to create a Student object and store a list of that.

Comment: That's actually what I think I need to do!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
```

inside switch

```
case 1:
    String name=input.nextLine();
    al.add(name);
    break;
case 2:
    al.remove(name_to_be_removed);
    break;
case 3:
    if(al.contains(name)){
      System.out.println("true");
     }
     else
       System.out.println("false");
      break;
case 4:
     System.out.println(al.toArray());
     break;
case 5:
     System.out.println(al.size());
     break;
default:
     ....
```